# How to get the data from JSON representation in google API

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm new to developing android apps on unreal engine. I wonder if I can get the data in JSON representation in google API in this link: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products

I try to find the link to access this data but I failed.

Thanks for the solution in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've tried to get the data from google in unreal engine by using http request. I used the plugin in unreal called OnlineSubsystemUtils that provide me "Make In-app purchase V2" blueprint (also called InAppPurchaseQueryCallbackProxy2 in c++ source code) and this blueprint gives me back the data that I'm not sure it is a token from in app purchase. I've looked in the api document and the way to get the data is using the get method in the document, and I need 3 parameters, the package name, the productid which I've already known these two parameters but I don't know how to get the token